# Minimize efforts with foreach

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a script that will download users from a db table and attach a new random IP to each user based on his state.

The problem is that I wrote a lot of code and there is still much Copy/Paste job to be done if I keep it with this approach.

Can someone point me to the right direction on how to properly do that?

So first I have 50 of these:

```
$California_Text = file_get_contents('state/California.txt');
$California_textArray = explode("\n", $California_Text);
$Idaho_Text = file_get_contents('state/Idaho.txt');
$Idaho_textArray = explode("\n", $Idaho_Text);
$Illinois_Text = file_get_contents('state/Illinois.txt');
$Illinois_textArray = explode("\n", $Illinois_Text);
$Indiana_Text = file_get_contents('state/Illinois.txt');
$Indiana_textArray = explode("\n", $Indiana_Text);
$Iowa_Text = file_get_contents('state/Iowa.txt');
```

Then I have 50 of these:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    if (isset($row["state"])) {

        foreach ($row as $value){
            $California_randArrayIndexNum = array_rand($California_textArray);
            $p_California = $California_textArray[$California_randArrayIndexNum];

            $Texas_randArrayIndexNum = array_rand($Texas_textArray);
            $p_Texas = $Texas_textArray[$Texas_randArrayIndexNum];

            $Alabama_randArrayIndexNum = array_rand($Alabama_textArray);
            $p_Alabama = $Alabama_textArray[$Alabama_randArrayIndexNum];

            $Alaska_randArrayIndexNum = array_rand($Alaska_textArray);
            $p_Alaska = $Texas_textArray[$Alaska_randArrayIndexNum];

            $Arizona_randArrayIndexNum = array_rand($Arizona_textArray);
            $p_Arizona = $California_textArray[$Arizona_randArrayIndexNum];
.....
```

Then I have 50 of these:

```
if ($row["state"] == "california") {
            $stateip = $p_California; 
        }
        else if ($row["state"] == "texas") {
            $stateip = $p_Texas;
        }
        else if ($row["state"] == "alabama") {
            $stateip = $p_Alabama;
        }
        else if ($row["state"] == "alaska") {
            $stateip = $p_Alaska;
        }
```

I'm pretty much sure that it's a bad approach.. Maybe there's a way to do all this with like 3 lines of `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
// holds your content
$state_content = [];

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    // check do we have state set
    if (!empty($row["state"])) {
        $stateip = getStateIpByName($row["state"]);
    }
}

/**
 *  Returns random IP
 */
function getStateIpByName($state_name) {
    $content = getStateContent($state_name);

    return $content[array_rand($content)];
}

/**
 * Returns your's state content by state name
 */
function getStateContent($state_name) {

    // checks do we already have content for this state
    if(!isset($state_content[$state_name])) {

        // generate file name
        $file_name = "state/";
        $file_name .= str_replace(" ", "", ucwords($state_name));
        $file_name .= ".txt";

        $state_text = file_get_contents($file_name);
        $state_content[$state_name] = explode("\n", $state_text);
    }

    return $state_content[$state_name];
}
```

There are probably some errors but you will get idea.

Comment: `getStateContent($state_name) {` throws a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in ` and I can't understand why that happens.

Comment: I missed function, maybe that was the issue? getStateContent is there to grab your content from text file. It will do that as you are looping records for each state. Maybe you will need to make some corrections here, I assumed your files have same name as states in database, only with first uppercase letter.

Comment: That worked like a charm but there is a small issue now: `Warning: file_get_contents(state/.txt)` & `Warning: file_get_contents(state/New york.txt)`. Basically on some cases it tries to load a file with no name (I don't have null variables) and sometimes it tries to load state files with a space in their name but my state variables look like: `NewYork` (no space).
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Just made some updates. I replaced isset($row["state"]) with empty($row["state"]) and removed space from state name.

Answer (score 0):

Store all states in an array and do all operations within a `foreach` block

```
 $states=['california',..];
 foreach($states as $state){
  //Your code for one state
  //Replace state name with $state variable
  }
```

Comment: I like this approach, but how do I change let's say `$XXX_Text` so it will appear as `$California_Text`? You said "//Replace state name with $state variable" but I guess if I do `$state_Text` it will just create a new variable instead of creating a new one for each state?